# Are you out if a bats slip from your hand and flew into striker’s wicket?

Tags: cricket

So we had an incident where a batsmen was struck on his head and his bat flew back leaving from his hands and went into his wicket.

Is it out?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an appeal is made, yes. [Law 29 The wicket is down](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/the-wicket-is-down):

> The wicket is put down if a bail is completely removed from the top of the stumps, or a stump is struck out of the ground [...] by the striker's bat not in hand

and [Law 35 Hit wicket](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/hit-wicket):

> The striker is out Hit wicket if, after the bowler has entered the delivery stride and while the ball is in play, his/her wicket is put down by either the striker’s bat or person [...] in any of the following circumstances: 
> in the course of any action taken by him/her in preparing to receive or in receiving a delivery,